# Cannot resolve Navigation Component default animations

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to use the default navigation animations in my navigation graph. But the default animations (for example `nav_default_pop_exit_anim` and `nav_default_pop_enter_anim`) are giving me:

*Cannot resolve symbol '@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim'. Validates Resource references inside Android XML files.*

In my `navigation_graph.xml`:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/MyFragment"
    android:name="com.my.app.mobile.MyFragment"
    android:label="MyFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_MyFragment_to_YourFragment"
        app:destination="@+id/YourFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_left_enter"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_right_exit"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/MyFragment" />
</fragment>
```

I'm using Android Studio 3.3 RC 2 and my gradle has:

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navVersion"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing:$navVersion"
```

where `navVersion = "1.0.0-alpha08"`

What's weird is that the Navigation Design view has access to these **default** animations. But when I switch to the Navigation Text view, those same **default** animations are red with warnings. Has anybody else encountered this problem? How do I get access to these default animations?

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, syncing Gradle, invalidating and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185964/navigation-component-no-transitions-to-select-in-drop-down/55185965#55185965), you should add the following lines in gradle:

```
def nav_version = "1.0.0-rc02"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

You used `implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion"`, I dont know what is the `ktx` in the end, try to remove it.