# Navigation component no transitions to select in drop down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I created navigation folder and navigation .xml file but in the navigation component under `Animations->Enter` there is no animations to choose from.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the gradle you should add those lines under dependencies:

```
def nav_version = "1.0.0-rc02"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

[image]